# Heroku Python Local Environment Variables

Tags: python, django, windows, heroku, environment-variables

Working on a heroku django project.

**Goal**: I want to run the server locally with same code on cloud too (makes sense).

**Problem**:
Environments differ from a linux server (heroku) to a local PC windows system.
Local environment variables differ from cloud Heroku config vars.
Heroku config vars can be setup easily using the CLI `heroku config:set TIMES=2`.

While setting up local env vars is a total mess.

I tried the following in cmd:
`py -c "import os;os.environ['Times']=2"` # To set an env var

Then ran `py -c "import os;os.environ.get('Times','Not Found')"` stdout: "Not Found".

After a bit of research it appeared to be that such env vars are stored temporarily per process/session usage.

**Solution theory**: Redirect `os.environ` to `.env` file of the root heroku project instead of the PC env vars. So I found this tool [direnv](https://direnv.net/) perfect for Unix-like OSs but not available for Windows.

`views.py` code (runs perfect on cloud, sick on the local machine):

```
import os
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Greeting

def index(request):
    # get method takes 2 parameters (env_var_string,return value if var is not found)
    times = int(os.environ.get('TIMES',3))

    return HttpResponse('<p>'+ 'Hello! ' * times+ '</p>')

def db(request):
    greeting = Greeting()
    greeting.save()
    greetings = Greeting.objects.all()
    return render(request, "db.html", {"greetings": greetings})
```

**Main Question**: Is there a proper way to hide secrets locally in windows and access them by `os.environ['KEY']`?

**Another solution theory**: I was wondering if a python virtual environment has it's own environment variables. If yes i activate a venv locally without affecting the cloud. Therefore `os.environ['KEY']` is redirected to the venv variables. Again it's just a theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use environment variables which you can get via `os.environ['KEY']`.
The same code will work on both local development and on Heroku.

On Heroku define these variables using ConfigVars `heroku config:set KEY=val` while locally (on Windows for example) define the same variables in an `.env` file (use [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to load them). The `.env` file is never committed with the source code.

Comment: One minute ago i saw the 'dotenv' solution. Yet I am not into trusting python modules that are 3rd-party. Could there be a way to see the credebility of its authors?

Comment: You know we are dealing with secrets here, keys and values, you got the point!

Comment: If you're concerned about trust, you have no reason to worry about the python-dotenv package. It's a highly used, well-maintained project: https://snyk.io/advisor/python/python-dotenv